# Buefy table backend-sorting doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, columnsorting, buefy

I have a huge data to display in a Buefy table and am trying to sort the columns using **backend-sorting**. But when I add the **backend-sorting** keyword in the table it doesn't sort.If i remove that then the table sorts only for that particular page , i have like 100 pages and i need to sort all together. Appreciate some help here , thanks. (Am completely new to vue and buefy , using c# in the backend)

```html
<b-table :data="data" striped hoverable paginated :loading="isLoading"
      backend-pagination :total="total" :per-page="perPage" @page-change="onPageChange"
      backend-sorting :default-sort="[sortField, sortOrder]" :default-sort-direction="defaultSortDirection" @sort="onSort">
      
 methods: {
    makePaging () {
      let paging = { 
        ordering: [
          {
            field: this.sortField,
            direction: this.sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'Ascending' : 'Descending'
          }
        ], 
        filtering: [],
        pageNumber: this.pageNumber - 1,
        resultsPerPage: this.perPage
      };      

      return paging;
    },

    async refreshData () {
      this.isLoading = true;

      let paging = this.makePaging();
      let response = await api[API_ENDPOINT](paging);

      this.res= response.data.Records;
      this.total = response.data.TotalRecords;
      this.isLoading = false;
    },

    onPageChange (newPage) {
      this.pageNumber = newPage;
      this.refreshData();
    },

    onSort (field, order) {
      this.sortField = field;
      this.sortOrder = order;
      this.refreshData();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I didn't use Buefy, but I checked the [buefy docs](https://buefy.github.io/documentation/table), **Async data** section. I found this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/pen?editors=1010) from the docs. I see that example has `@sort="onSort"` call on the `<b-table>`, which you are missing.  You need to provide the method that will be called for sorting

Comment: @ljubadr I tried the @sort="onSort" method but still couldn't sort the table.

Comment: If you place `console.log()` or `debugger;` in your `onSort()` method, does it get called?

Comment: Yes it is , the onSort() method gets called , am able to print the field and sort details .

Comment: Is it working then?

Comment: No , the arrows just go up and down there seems to be no action(sorting)

Comment: There should be ajax call being fired, check browser devtools, network panel. While there, check if correct **paging** is being sent. If you click column 1, does the ajax show correct parameters? If correct params are being sent, then you have problem with your backend sorting

Comment: I checked in network panel in devtools, data which it shows doesn't change in asc or desc order, sorting isn't happening.

Comment: Response data doesn't change? You need to check parameters that are being sent from network panel. When you change sort, params being sent should change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187094/discussion-between-ljubadr-and-meenu-shankar).